# Post form with ajax and then submit same form to other url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Why my form is not again submitting to another URL after ajax submit.

with the below script i want to post form with ajax and then submit same form to other url.

first my form will submit to Ajax URL (http://www.mywebsite.com/insertdata.php) and then it same form will submit to form action URL (http://www.example.com/mail.php)

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact_form" action="http://www.example.com/mail.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" data-track="formSubmit" name="contact_form">

 <!------Form Elements ------->
<input class="form-control submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/insertdata.php",
            type: "post",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(responce) {
                console.log(responce);
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: it is not fireing because you placed event.preventDefault();

Comment: In your sucess function try adding $("form").submit(); instead of return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `event.preventDefault();`
 
If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.This is stopping the form to submit to the url in `action` attribute.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {

              event.preventDefault();
              flag=false;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/insertdata.php",
                    type: "post",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(responce) {
                        console.log(responce);
                        return true;
                        $("form").off("submit");
                        $("form").trigger( "submit" )
                    }
                });      
        });
```

Comment: if i will remove   event.preventDefault();
then no ajax will work .. because form has active Action.

Comment: @PuzzledBoy edited the answer , might not be the correct way to do this but works!!

Answer (score 1):

In success function add a form submit.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/insertdata.php",
        type: "post",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(responce) {
            console.log(responce);
            $("form").submit();
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

UPdate: Can you use button click, it will work

```
$(".submit").on("click", function(event) {
```

Comment: you have to unbind your event handler before calling submit() second time. So first line becomes `$("form").on("submit.unbindme", function(event) {`, and before second submit you should add `$(this).off("submit.unbindme")`'

Answer (score 1):

```
   $("#contact_form").on("submit", function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/insertdata.php",
            type: "post",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
```